# Unable to remove site collection: Operation failed due to an error in Identity Mangement

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, delete

I've restored a site collection to a different SharePoint farm. Now i am trying to delete the site collection:

- Using Powershell:

  Remove-SPSite `http://farm/sites/Site_Collection`

Error:

```
Remove-SPSite : Operation failed due to an error in Identity Mangement
At line:1 char:14 + Remove-SPSite <<<<  http://farm/sites/Site_Collection + CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletRemoveSite:
   SPCmdletRemoveSite) [Remove-SPSite], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveSite
```

- Using Central Administration:

Operation failed due to an error in Identity Mangement

When i check the ULS logs, the corresponding correlation ID only mentions the same error "Operation failed due to an error in Identity Mangement".

How can i remove this site collection and / or fix the notification so i can delete the site collection?

Answer (score 1):

Open Power Shell as Administrator, it should fix the problem.

or use -Force attribute.

**Edit**

ummm how about trying this,

```
Remove-SPSite-Identity http://farm/sites/Site_Collection -GradualDelete
```

Comment: Retried the Remove-SPSite PowerShell command while in an administrator PowerShell window, but i still get the same error. :(

Comment: Alright, just retried using Remove-SPSite -Identity http://farm/sites/Site_Colle
ction -GradualDelete. I still get the same error.

Comment: when you try GradualDelete, do you get any error, ignore uls logs for the moment

Comment: When using the GradualDelete parameter, i get the same error "Remove-SPSite : Operation failed due to an error in Identity Mangement".

Comment: do you have access to spfarm account, to me it seems like you don't have enough permissions, however when you use GradualDelete, it adds a timer job and which later on deletes the site collection, it could also be User profile service problem, can you check if it's running and synchronized

Comment: I've opened the PowerShell window using my Farm Account. I still get the same error "Operation failed due to an error in Identity Mangement"